# Finding closest number to average of 3 random numbers

Tags: java, random, average

I need to find the closest number to average of 3 random numbers.
Program will generate `a`, `b` and `c`, calculate average from this numbers and then show us which of the random numbers is closest to our average.
I have got this right now:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class AvgRnd {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int a = rnd.nextInt(11);
    int b = rnd.nextInt(37)-13;
    int c = rnd.nextInt(54)+34;
    System.out.println(a+"  "+b+"  "+ c);
    int avg = (a+b+c)/3;
    System.out.println(avg);
}
}
```

Comment: So, find the difference between each number and the average. Find the lowest difference, and you have your answer.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have already written?

Comment: isn't it always the one in the middle?, I tried a few cases and it seems to always be

Comment: @RobertColumbia it doesnt find out which of the input numbers is closest to the average...

Comment: What happens if 2 or 3 numbers are the same?

Comment: @Bentaye- tricky! It should print these 2 numbers (3 its impossible)

Comment: @sleepToken :  
 `if (avg - a < avg - b || avg - a < avg - c) {
              System.out.println(a);
        }
          else if (avg - b < avg - a || avg - b < avg - c) {
              System.out.println(b);
        }
          else if (avg - c < avg - a || avg - c < avg - b) {
              System.out.println(c);
        }`

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question correctly
Math.abs() is what you are looking for.

```
//example:
//a = 8, b = 7, c = 57 --> avg = 24

int nearest = Math.abs(avg - yourValue);
//this returns the absolute difference to your average value
//in this case int nearest for a would be 16
//and for b  nearest = 17 
//for c nearest = 33
```

You just need to compare those values and get the smallest value of those three, which shuld be the value you are looking for.

I hope this was understandbale, if not just ask again ;)